Did Bhagavad Gita have any verse in which Krishna said that he is parbramh
Did Bhagavad Gita contain any verse in which Krishna declared himself parbramh?

Arjuna refers to Krishna as para brahman.

अर्जुन उवाच


परं ब्रह्म परं धाम पवित्रं परमं भवान्।
पुरुषं शाश्वतं दिव्यमादिदेवमजं विभुम्।। Gita 10.12।।

Arjuna said - You are the Supreme Brahman, the supreme abode (or the supreme light), the supreme purifier, eternal, divine Person, the primeval God, unborn and omnipresent.

The question is where Krishna declared himself as brahman

Yes, several, in fact.
A few are:

Bg 10.8 - I am the source of all spiritual and material worlds. Everything emanates from Me.

(Description matches that of Brahman)

Bg 14.27 - And I am the basis of the impersonal Brahman, which is immortal, imperishable and eternal and is the constitutional position of ultimate happiness.

(explicit declaration)

Bg 15.13 - I enter into each planet, and by My energy they stay in orbit. I become the moon and thereby supply the juice of life to all vegetables.

(Once again, declaration of qualities that match up with Brahman)
Hope that is a good answer.

The following verse can be interpreted thus:

मत्त: परतरं नान्यत्किञ्चिदस्ति धनञ्जय । मयि सर्वमिदं प्रोतं सूत्रे
मणिगणा इव ॥
Translation:
O conqueror of wealth, there is no truth superior to Me. Everything
rests upon Me, as pearls are strung on a thread.
[Bhagavad Gita 7.7]

Once they attain the Brahman souls never take rebirth again. Krishna declares that he is this final Abode to reach:

अव्यक्तोऽक्षर इत्युक्तस्तमाहु: परमां गतिम् ।  यं प्राप्य न निवर्तन्ते तद्धाम परमं मम ॥ २१
Translation:
That which the Vedāntists describe as unmanifest and infallible, that
which is known as the supreme destination, that place from which once attained no one ever returns – that is My supreme abode.
[Bhagavad Gita 8.21]


Kṛṣṇa confirms His sole position as Parabrahman at many places in Bhagavad Gita. But unfortunately due to many unauthorised impersonal interpretations people get mislead into thinking of Brahman as all in all.
1) Kṛṣṇa says in BG 7.7

mattaḥ parataraṁ nānyat kiñcid asti dhanañjaya
mayi sarvam idaṁ protaṁ sūtre maṇi-gaṇā iva
“O conquerer of wealth [Arjuna], there is no Truth superior to Me.
Everything rests upon Me, as pearls are strung on a thread.”

Krsna says here that no one is superior to Him, means Brahman becomes subordinate to Him. Thus He declares Himself as Parabrahman. He is para tattva or summon bonum, the complete absolute truth.
2) In BG 7.24 Krsna says,

avyaktaṁ vyaktim āpannaṁ manyante mām abuddhayaḥ
paraṁ bhāvam ajānanto mamāvyayam anuttamam
“Unintelligent men, who know Me not, think that I have assumed this
form and personality. Due to their small knowledge, they do not know
My higher nature, which is changeless and supreme.”

Many consider that, the avatars of Lord come from Brahman and they assume some name and form. But here it's denied and declared that such people possess small intellect. They do not know 'param bhava' of the Lord, which is indeed Parabrahman.
3) In BG 10.8 Kṛṣṇa says,

ahaṁ sarvasya prabhavo mattaḥ sarvaṁ pravartate
iti matvā bhajante māṁ budhā bhāva-samanvitāḥ
“I am the source of all spiritual and material worlds. Everything
emanates from Me. The wise who know this perfectly engage in My
devotional service and worship Me with all their hearts.”

This verse says, everything emanates from Kṛṣṇa, which is very similar to Vedanta 1.1.2 - Janmady asya yatah. Indeed we can clearly declare that Brahman is also emanation from the personal body of Lord Kṛṣṇa, thus making Him Parabrahman.
4) In 10.12-13 Arjuna also confirms as follows

arjuna uvāca
paraṁ brahma paraṁ dhāma pavitraṁ paramaṁ bhavān
puruṣaṁ śāśvataṁ divyam ādi-devam ajaṁ vibhum
āhus tvām ṛṣayaḥ sarve devarṣir nāradas tathā
asito devalo vyāsaḥ svayaṁ caiva bravīṣi me
“Arjuna said: You are the Supreme Brahman, the ultimate, the supreme
abode and purifier, the Absolute Truth and the eternal divine person.
You are the primal God, transcendental and original, and You are the
unborn and all-pervading beauty. All the great sages such as Nārada,
Asita, Devala, and Vyāsa proclaim this of You, and now You Yourself
are declaring it to me.”

Listening to all the previous statements of Kṛṣṇa in 7.7, 7.24, 10.8, Arjuna being the perfect recipient of Bhagavad Gita also concluded His opinion on the position of Lord Kṛṣṇa. He clearly declared Kṛṣṇa to be Parabrahman in 10.12. One may argue that Arjuna is dear devotee and friend of Kṛṣṇa (BG 4.3) so He might be buttering Kṛṣṇa as it's quite common in friendship. But immediately in 10.13, Arjuna supports His statement by the conclusion of various acaryas like Narada, Vyasa, Asita & Devala. One may note that Narada and Vyasa are empowered lila incarnations of Kṛṣṇa Himself as confirmed in Srimad Bhagavatam 1.3.8 & 1.3.21. So it's again Kṛṣṇa Himself declaring Himself to be Parabrahman.
5) In BG 13.13 Kṛṣṇa says,

jñeyaṁ yat tat pravakṣyāmi yaj jñātvāmṛtam aśnute
anādi mat-paraṁ brahma na sat tan nāsad ucyate
“I shall now explain the knowable, knowing which you will taste the
eternal. This is beginningless, and it is subordinate to Me. It is
called Brahman, the spirit, and it lies beyond the cause and effect of
this material world.”

Again here Kṛṣṇa says, 'mat para Brahma' which means He stands superior to Brahman. One may interpret it in reverse order that, Brahman is superior to Kṛṣṇa. But this statement contradicts the other verses so the previous statement of Brahman being subordinate is concluded.
6) In BG 14.27 Kṛṣṇa says,

brahmaṇo hi pratiṣṭhāham amṛtasyāvyayasya ca
śāśvatasya ca dharmasya sukhasyaikāntikasya ca
“And I am the basis of the impersonal Brahman, which is the
constitutional position of ultimate happiness, and which is immortal,
imperishable and eternal.”

One of the crystal clear verses on subordination of Brahman to Lord Kṛṣṇa. Srila Prabhupada says in SB 2.5.11, Purport as follows -

“Lord Kṛṣṇa is the background of the brahmajyoti (brahmaṇo hi
pratiṣṭhāham). In the Nirukti, or Vedic dictionary, the import of
pratiṣṭhā is mentioned as “that which establishes.” So the brahmajyoti
is not independent or self-sufficient. Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa is ultimately
the creator of the brahmajyoti, mentioned in this verse as sva-rociṣā,
or the effulgence of the transcendental body of the Lord. This
brahmajyoti is all-pervading, and all creation is made possible by its
power; therefore the Vedic hymns declare that everything that exists
is being sustained by the brahmajyoti (sarvaṁ khalv idaṁ brahma).
Therefore the potent seed of all creation is the brahmajyoti, and the
same brahmajyoti, unlimited and unfathomed, is established by the
Lord. Therefore the Lord (Śrī Kṛṣṇa) is ultimately the supreme cause
of all creation (ahaṁ sarvasya prabhavaḥ).”

7) In BG 15.15 Kṛṣṇa says,

vedaiś ca sarvair aham eva vedyo
vedānta-kṛd veda-vid eva cāham
"By all the Vedas am I to be known; indeed I am the compiler of
Vedānta, and I am the knower of the Vedas."

From this verse we can understand that if Kṛṣṇa was not Parabrahman then He would have said Brahman as ultimate goal of Vedas, but He says "I" or Parabrahman is goal as also supported by 14.27.
8) In 18.50 Kṛṣṇa says about how can one attain Brahman and in 18.51-53 He speaks about qualities required to attain Brahman, thus finally in 18.54 He says as follows

brahma-bhūtaḥ prasannātmā
na śocati na kāṅkṣati
samaḥ sarveṣu bhūteṣu
mad-bhaktiṁ labhate parām
"One who is thus transcendentally situated at once realizes the
Supreme Brahman. He never laments nor desires to have anything; he is
equally disposed to every living entity. In that state he attains pure
devotional service unto Me."

Bhakti process is placed superior to Brahman realisation or a Vaishnava is placed superior to Brahmana or personal abode of Kṛṣṇa is placed superior to Impersonal Brahman as confirmed by Arjuna in 10.12 as Param Brahma Param Dhama. Abode of the Lord is said as Param even to Brahman, as further said in 18.55, visate tad anantaram, devotee enters the unlimited eternal Kingdom of Kṛṣṇa.
9) In Srimad Bhagavatam 1.2.11 Suta Goswami says,

vadanti tat tattva-vidas tattvaṁ yaj jñānam advayam
brahmeti paramātmeti bhagavān iti śabdyate
"Learned transcendentalists who know the Absolute Truth call this
nondual substance Brahman, Paramātmā or Bhagavān."

This nature of absolute truth is discussed in Bhagavad Gita also in 18.54, 18.61 and 18.66, where Brahman, Paramatma and Bhagavan features are discussed, each one progressive than the latter. In 11th chapter also the all pervading universal form is shown (Brahman), then the four handed Supersoul (Paramatma) and finally the all beautiful two handed feature of Kṛṣṇa (Bhagavan).
So all these statements if we study, analyse and understand properly then we come to the conclusion of Kṛṣṇa being Superior to Brahman, viz., Parabrahman. More specifically He is realised in 3 aspects of Brahman, Paramatma and Bhagavan. The Bhagavan being the topmost realisation of the absolute truth. All verse and translations are from the original books of His Divine Grace A. C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Srila Prabhupada.
